# kivy: KeyError: (3385,) in widget.py

Tags: python, kivy, destructor, keyerror

When trying to exectue following code (edited version from the [kivy-designer](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer), stands under the MIT license):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self._buttons = {}

    super(PlaygroundSizeView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    for title, values in self.default_sizes:
        grid = StackLayout(orientation="lr-tb", size_hint=(1, None))

        def sort_sizes(item):
            return item[1][1] * item[1][0]

        values = sorted(values, key=sort_sizes, reverse=True)
        for name, size in values:
            btn = ToggleButton(text='', markup=True, size_hint=(0.25, 0.25))
            btntext = ('%s\n[color=777777][size=%d]%dx%d[/size][/color]' %
                       (name, btn.font_size * 0.8, size[0], size[1]))
            btn.text = btntext
            btn.bind(on_press=partial(self.set_size, size))
            grid.add_widget(btn)
            self._buttons[name] = btn

        item = AccordionItem(title=title)
        _sv = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False)
        _sv.add_widget(grid)
        item.add_widget(_sv)
        self.accordion.add_widget(item)

    self.accordion.select(self.accordion.children[-1])

    self.update_buttons()
```

I get following Error 7 times in a row with different numbers before the program stops:

> Exception ignored in: functools.partial(, 3385)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:\Programme(x86)\Python\Kivy Virtual Environment\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 239, in _widget_destructor
>   KeyError: (3385,)

It only appeared after I edited the code and added `ScrollView` at #1. I think it might be that python is trying to garbage collect `ScrollView` but is somehow unable to.

Linue 239 of widget.py is the `del` line of following function:

```
def _widget_destructor(uid, r):
    # Internal method called when a widget is deleted from memory. the only
    # thing we remember about it is its uid. Clear all the associated callbacks
    # created in kv language.
    del _widget_destructors[uid]
    Builder.unbind_widget(uid)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That line #1 has a typo in add_widget.
Are you sure that add_widget returns the parent widget?
I suggest you make a ScrollView first, then add the grid, then add the item to accordion.

Comment: That is a legitimate concern - I corrected my code, thanks! It doesn't change the outcome, sadly.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your effort, and welcome to Stackoverflow! Just one thing: this sort of content (A question and a suggestion to try something) belongs into the comments.

Comment: As a new user, I'm unable to comment on the opening question. My Kivy is a bit rusty as well... but I remember it's good practice to keep explicit references to child objects in the parent to disable python garbage collection.